# How do you make a fetch call in JS catch from a Go server?

Tags: go

I have a JS frontend and a Go backend. On the server, when I respond with an error, I use

```
http.Error(w, `{"err":"bad request"}`, http.StatusBadRequest)
```

and on my frontend, I have

```
fetch(`${API_URL}/dosomething`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log('data', data))
  .catch(err => console.log('err', err));
```

The error is sent over just fine, but the fetch call in JS does not catch. The `err` object just gets passed to `.then(data => console.log('data', data))`. What should I do on my server to make the fetch call catch with a string for an `err` value (so I don't have to respond with json).

Comment: Your backend is fine; modify your client so that you throw an error on if `!res.ok`.

Comment: `fetch` does not `throw` in this case because the request didn't fail. It returned a response, and that response was a status code 400 with a response body. If you want to treat that as a failure, you'll need to do so in your own logic.

Answer (score 3):

> A `fetch()` promise will reject with a `TypeError` **when a network
>   error is encountered** or CORS is misconfigured on the server-side,
>   although this usually means permission issues or similar — a 404 does
>   not constitute a network error, for example. An accurate check for a
>   successful `fetch()` would include checking that the promise resolved,
>   then checking that the `Response.ok` property has a value of true.

[Per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)